# How to use intent to launch Add Contact activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, contacts

I'm trying to launch add contact activity from my application. I've known how to call contact activity, but still unknown how to launch "Add Contact". I'm a beginner learning Android, please be specific. Thank you.

Comment: can you please provide the code you are currently using ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(
            ContactsContract.Intents.SHOW_OR_CREATE_CONTACT,
            Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber));
        intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.EXTRA_FORCE_CREATE, true);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
 Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT_OR_EDIT);
 i.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);   
 startActivity(i);
```